# Calling webservice from c# forms app

Tags: c#, web-services

I have a webservice with a method in it.

I can call it fine from a c# webapp using the following:

```
MyWebService mws = new MyWebService();
mws.MyMethod();
```

However, if I try and call it from a c# forms app, I add the webservice in the same way.

This time if I use intellisense, I get the following methods / properties:

```
MyMethodRequest
MyMethodRequestBody
MyMethodResponse
MyMethodResponseBody
MyWebServiceSoap
MyWebServiceSoapChannel
MyWebServiceSoapClient
```

How do I call my method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

most probably:

```
MyWebServiceSoapClient client = new MyWebServiceSoapClient();
client.MyMethod();
```